# Segmentation error but I don't know why

Tags: c, arrays, void

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#define MAX_SIZE 100
```

I am trying to quicksort an array of 2D points based upon their distance from the origin but my code hits a `Seg fault` after the first `scanf`.

```
typedef struct point{
double x;
double y;
double dist;
    } point;

void sortpoints(point arr[], int low, int high);
void printpoints(point arr[], int n);
```

Sortpoints is just a manipulation of a quicksort in ordering an array of `Point structs` depending on the value of `Point.dist`

```
void sortpoints(point arr[], int low, int high){
    int piv, i, j;
    piv = low;
    i = low;
    j = high;
    point box;
    if(low < high){
        while(i<j){
            while((arr[i].dist)<=(arr[piv].dist) && i<= high)
                i++;
            }
            while((arr[j].dist) > (arr[piv].dist) && j>= low)
                j--;
            }
            if(i<j){
                box = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = box;
            }
        box = arr[j];
        arr[j] = arr[piv];
        arr[piv] = box;
        sortpoints(arr, low, j-1);
        sortpoints(arr, j+1, high);

    }
```

Printpoints just prints the points in order of their distances from the origin

```
    void printpoints(point arr[], int n){
        int i; for(i = 0; i <= n; i++){
                    printf("(%.2lf, %.2lf)\n", arr[i].x, arr[i].y);
                }
    }
```

The user enters the number of points and value of the points in the form (point.x, point.y)

```
int main(){

    point pointa;
    point pointarray[MAX_SIZE];
    int n=0;
    printf("how many points would you like to enter?\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    if(n<MAX_SIZE){
        int i;
        for(i=0; i<n ; i++){
            scanf("(%lf,%lf)", &pointa.x, &pointa.y);
            pointa.dist = sqrt(pointa.x*pointa.x + pointa.y*pointa.y);
            pointarray[i] = pointa;
        }
        sortpoints(pointarray, 0, n-1);
        printpoints(pointarray, n);}
    else{
        printf("sorry, not a valid array size\n");
    }



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's been a while since I repassed operator precedence in C... can you try with `&(pointa.x)`?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply! just tried that, no luck unfortunately.

Comment: @SJuan76 the element selection operator `.` has higher precedence than address-of `&` and is run first.

Answer (score 1):

When I changed this line:

```
scanf("(%lf,%lf)", &pointa.x, &pointa.y);
```

To this:

```
scanf("%lf,%lf", &pointa.x, &pointa.y);
```

The point values were actually being read in, with the parens there nothing gets read in, I don't see anything in the documentation on `scanf` about this though, is anyone familiar with this?

You sorting code seems to go into infinite recursion and cause a stack overflow however.

Answer (score 1):

I've got stack overflow.

Your program calls function `sortpoints`, and calls itself too (`sortpoints` calls `sortpoints`). But i cant see where `sortpoints` must stop!

As a result, `j-1` goes under null, and `arr[j]` is not valid at all.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is with your braces. I have reformatted your sortpoints function slightly so it is clearer where each basic block actually is.

```
void sortpoints(point arr[], int low, int high){
    int piv, i, j;
    piv = low;
    i = low;
    j = high;
    point box;

    if(low < high){
        while(i<j){
            while((arr[i].dist)<=(arr[piv].dist) && i<= high)
                i++;
        }

        while((arr[j].dist) > (arr[piv].dist) && j>= low)
                j--;
    }

    if(i<j){
        box = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[j];
        arr[j] = box;
    }

    box = arr[j];
    arr[j] = arr[piv];
    arr[piv] = box;
    sortpoints(arr, low, j-1);
    sortpoints(arr, j+1, high);
}
```

It should be evident now that your segfault is the result of accidental infinite recursion. This is a good argument for using `{ }` for your loops, even with a single statement.